# Trying to POST to a service and get response to monitor. But cannot get the Javascript to work

Tags: javascript, coldfusion

I am trying to get two separate services to monitor a platform but can only get one or the other to work at one time. I user a .BAT to hit the service and they seem to be connecting and working. But the problem occurs when i try to dimply the returned response. I have been working forever and still cannot get it. Looked through Stack for any ideas but couldn't find anything.

So the first thing were doing is stating the JS:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

<!--
function initPing() {
/* called from Body onLoad above */

Ping();
var AckCheck = window.setInterval(function(){Ping()},10000);

}


function Ping() { 


xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();


xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
     document.getElementById('IPAWS_PING_PROD').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText +           document.getElementById('IPAWS_PING_PROD').innerHTML;

  }
 }



xmlhttp.open("GET","../ipaws/ping_prod.cfm?    COGID=#session.prod_cog_id#&account_id=#session.account_id#",true);
xmlhttp.send();




}

// -->

<!--
function initPing2() {
/* called from Body onLoad above */

Ping2();
var AckCheck2 = window.setInterval(function(){Ping2()},10000);

}


function Ping() { 


xmlhttp2=new XMLHttpRequest();


xmlhttp2.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp2.readyState==4 && xmlhttp2.status==200)
    {
     document.getElementById('IPAWS_PING_TEST').innerHTML = xmlhttp2.responseText + document.getElementById('IPAWS_PING_TEST').innerHTML;

    }
  }



 xmlhttp2.open("GET","../ipaws/ping_test.cfm?   COGID=#session.test_cog_id#&account_id=#session.account_id#",true);
 xmlhttp2.send();




 }

// -->
</script>
```

And here is how we call the functions:

```
 <div id="IPAWS_PING_TEST" style="width:19px;height:20px;overflow:hidden;float:left;text-align:left;font-size:16px;font-weight:bold;"></div>


 <div id="IPAWS_PING_TEST" style="width:19px;height:20px;overflow:hidden;float:left;text-align:left;font-size:16px;font-weight:bold;"></div>
```

So here is an example of the pinging page:

```
<cfparam name="URL.COGID" default="">

<cfexecute name="C:\IPAWS\_ack2.bat" 
arguments="#URL.COGID#" timeout="30"  
errorVariable="errout2" variable="response2"/>
<cfoutput>
<CFIF errout2 neq "">
<!---
<b style="color:red;" title="ERROR (RETRYING) #timeformat(now(),'h:mm:ss tt')#">&bull;</b>
--->
<cfelseif response2 contains "PONG">
<b style="color:##00ff00;" title="#URL.COGID# CONNECTED: #timeformat(now(),'h:mm:ss tt')#"><!---    &lang;&bull;&rang;--->
<img src="connected2.png" width="18" alt="Connected">
</b>
<cfelse>
<b style="color:##ff9933;" title="RETRYING: #timeformat(now(),'h:mm:ss tt')#">&lang;&bull;&rang;</b>
</cfif></cfoutput>
</script>
```

We're getting successful responses ("PONG") but just cannot display them both at the same time. Any idea? I wish i was more proficient at JS.

Thanks!

*Edit*

I decided to just try to simplify everything and use the following code:

```
<cfhttp url="new.wensnetwork.com/ipaws/…" method="get" result="cfhttp">
<div id="IPAWS_PING_TEST" style="width:19px;height:20px;overflow:hidden;float:left;text-align:left;font-size:16px;font-weight:bold;">#cfhttp.filecontent#</div>
```

Comment: I decided to just try to simplify everything and use the following coded:                 
                <cfhttp url="https://new.wensnetwork.com/ipaws/ping_prod.cfm?COGID=#session.prod_cog_id#" method="get" result="cfhttp">
                <div id="IPAWS_PING_TEST" style="width:19px;height:20px;overflow:hidden;float:left;text-align:left;font-size:16px;font-weight:bold;">#cfhttp.filecontent#</div>

Comment: But is there a way to have it reload every 20 secs? Thanks!

Comment: Reloads can be done on the Javascript. There are lots of examples of that. Just look up "javascript setTimeout"

Comment: I am not sure what the issue is you experience with the batch file, because you are not mentioning anything of issues with it. If you do, please post the batch file code, if you don't, perhaps the batch-file tag is not relevant here.